# posting PHP to URL via WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, php, .net, api, curl

Here my code is

```
$url="http://www.example.com";
    $post_data="username=dssasdasd&extension=123";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($output, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($status == 200)
    {echo "Successfully Sended";}
    else{echo "Try Again";}
curl_close ($ch);
```

I need to send this data using Webclient C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code sample

```
             string url = "http://Example.com/admin"
             using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
             {                    
                 var data = new NameValueCollection();
                 data.Add("username","asdsdsad");
                 data.Add("extension", 123);                    

                 var Bytecode = client.UploadValues(url, data);
                 string htmlCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytecode, 0, Bytecode.Length);
                 // Or you can get the file content without saving it:

             }
```

Finally, You will get response in htmcode